# Make individual image enlarge on click with vue

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I am trying to make like an image modal, I am using html, css and vue and I am new to this, when I click on an image all of them enlarge, what can i do to only make one of the them enlarge since  I am looping through an array for the images.

```
<div v-if="visible" class="food__menu">
          <a href="#" class="food__list" v-for="food in foods" :key="food">
            <div class="food__image">
              <img
                :src="food.image"
                :class="{fullWidthImage : fullWidthImage }"
                @click="fullWidthImage = !fullWidthImage"
              />
            </div>
            <div class="food__details">
              <span class="food__name">{{food.name}}</span>
              <span class="food__type">{{food.type}}</span>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
```

```
.fullWidthImage {
  width: 300px !important;
  height: 400px !important;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
}

.food__image img {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      toggle: false,
      visible: false,
      mealTitle: false,
      fullWidthImage: false,
      foods: [
        {
          image: require("../assets/images/food.png"),
          name: "potatoes",
          type: "Carbohydrate"
        },
        {
          image: require("../assets/images/food1.png"),
          name: " rice",
          type: "Protein"
        },
        {
          image: require("../assets/images/food2.png"),
          name: "Lamb",
          type: "Carbohydrate"
        },
}
}
}
```

I am trying to do this
[image]

but when I click on one all enlarge, please help
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are storing the `fullWidthImage` on a component data level, which is not scoped to individual images. Therefore, when it flips to true, all images will be enlarged.

You can instead store the index of the image you want to be full width. This will allow you to conditionally toggle the class based on the index of the image.

```
<a href="#" class="food__list" v-for="(food, i) in foods" :key="food">
    <div class="food__image">
        <img
            :src="food.image"
            :class="getImageClass(i)"
            @click="onImageClick(i)"
        />
    </div>
</a>
```

Then, in the component, create the following methods:

```
data: {
    fullWidthImageIndex: null,
    // ... other data here
},
methods: {
    getImageClass: function(i) {
        return {
            'fullWidthImage': this.fullWidthImageIndex === i
        };
    },
    onImageClick: function(i) {
        if (this.fullWidthImageIndex === i) {
            this.fullWidthImageIndex = null;
        } else {
            this.fullWidthImageIndex = i;
        }
    }
}
```